# net.corda.testing.node.internal.ListenProcessDeathException: The process that was expected to listen on localhost:10000 has died with status: 1

Tags: java, corda

Getting the below errors while building the sample `corDapp cordapp-example-release-V3` :

> [INFO ] 14:29:29,050 [driver-pool-thread-0] (NodeInfoFilesCopier.kt:63) network.NodeInfoFilesCopier.addConfig - Now watching: C:\Users\purni\Downloads\cordapp-example-release-V3\build\20180413-085907.908\PartyA {}
>   [INFO ] 14:29:29,050 [driver-pool-thread-0] (DriverDSLImpl.kt:814) internal.DriverDSLImpl.startOutOfProcessNode - Starting out-of-process Node PartyA, debug port is 5008, jolokia monitoring port is not enabled {}

Encountered exception in node startup:  `net.corda.testing.node.internal.ListenProcessDeathException`: The process that was expected to listen on `localhost:10000` has died with `status: 1`

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: net.corda.testing.node.internal.ListenProcessDeathException: The process that was expected to listen on localhost:10000 has died with status: 1
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
>       at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.get(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
>       at com.example.NodeDriver.lambda$main$0(NodeDriver.java:44)
>       at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImplKt.genericDriver(DriverDSLImpl.kt:958)
>       at net.corda.testing.driver.Driver.driver(Driver.kt:186)
>       at com.example.NodeDriver.main(NodeDriver.java:32)
>   Caused by: net.corda.testing.node.internal.ListenProcessDeathException: The process that was expected to listen on localhost:10000 has died with status: 1
>       at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$addressMustBeBoundFuture$1.invoke(InternalTestUtils.kt:39)
>       at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$addressMustBeBoundFuture$1.invoke(InternalTestUtils.kt)
>       at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$poll$task$1.run(InternalTestUtils.kt:86)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Process finished with exit code 0.

Comment: Were you running from the command line or IntelliJ? Did all the processes fail, or just certain processes (e.g. the webserver processes)?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I am having the same issue on a fresh clone repo.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue. Just install the latest version of java 8 (java 8u181).
This issue will definitely get resolved with this. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html.
Corda works only on latest version of JVM. Use latest version if IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.6 community version