# java.io.NotSerializableException: Defined setter for parameter eligibleCurrency takes parameter of type interface

Tags: java, corda

Trying to migrate from Corda V1 to V3. It was working fine in V1 but after using Corda V3 its throwing below error -

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState ->
>   data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) -> Defined setter for
>   parameter eligibleCurrency takes parameter of type interface
>   java.util.List yet underlying type is java.util.List
>   -> class com.xxx.agreementnegotiation.state.AgreementNegotiationState
>
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
>     atjava.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
>     at
>   net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.get(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
>     at
>   com.xxx.agreementnegotiation.api.AgreementNegotiationApi.startInitFlow(AgreementNegotiationApi.java:95)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState ->
>   data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) -> Defined setter for
>   parameter eligibleCurrency takes parameter of type interface
>   java.util.List yet underlying type is java.util.List
>   -> class com.xxx.agreementnegotiation.state.AgreementNegotiationState

Some part of my state

```
public class AgreementNegotiationState extends AgreementStateTemplate implements QueryableState {
private String baseCurrency;
private List<String> eligibleCurrency;
private int deliveryAmount;

public String getBaseCurrency() {
    return baseCurrency;
}

public void setBaseCurrency(String baseCurrency) {
    this.baseCurrency = baseCurrency;
}

public List<String> getEligibleCurrency() {
    return eligibleCurrency;
}

public void setEligibleCurrency(List<String> eligibleCurrency) {
    this.eligibleCurrency = eligibleCurrency;
}

public int getDeliveryAmount() {
    return deliveryAmount;
}

public void setDeliveryAmount(int deliveryAmount) {
    this.deliveryAmount = deliveryAmount;
}
```

}

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Corda 3. It will be fixed in Corda 4.

In the meantime, the workaround is to change `eligibleCurrency` to a `List<?>`, and cast its elements as required:

```
private List<?> eligibleCurrency;

public List<?> getEligibleCurrency() {
    return eligibleCurrency;
}

public void setEligibleCurrency(List<?> eligibleCurrency) {
    this.eligibleCurrency = eligibleCurrency;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but now im getting -net.corda.testing.node.internal.ListenProcessDeathException: The process that was expected to listen on localhost:10000 has died with status: 1. Please respond on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813946/net-corda-testing-node-internal-listenprocessdeathexception-the-process-that-wa .  I have added my question as well

Answer (score 0):

As per corda V3 , Collections are immutable so you cannot add to the existing collection.The Solution is create a function which take the copy of the existing collection and add the item in it and finally referenced it to the eligibleCurrency list.

```
private Collection<SupportingDocument> supportingDocs;
public void addSupportingDoc(SupportingDocument supportingDoc) {

    //since corda 3.1 has unmodifiable collection
    List<SupportingDocument> suppDoc = new ArrayList<SupportingDocument>();
    for(SupportingDocument existingDoc : supportingDocs){
        suppDoc.add(existingDoc);
    }
    // adding new document
    suppDoc.add(supportingDoc);
    this.supportingDocs = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(suppDoc);
}
```

I hope , it makes sense